# What is default css display value for react web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was passing upwork test for react.js and I have got this question, I realy don't know, and google/react documentation don't help me. Can anyone know? it is very interesting to me)[image]

Comment: What do you mean? It depends on what HTML you're using and if you have any CSS of your own.

Comment: It mens, correct answer 'inherit'?

Comment: Nonsense question, leave feedback.

Comment: What is the right answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A React application is not an element. It doesn't have a default value for any CSS property.

Comment: I thought the same thing, there was no such option, please Look at the screenshot in my first post.
P/S I've chose inherit)

Comment: @VadymPetryshyn — The test is asking a nonsense question.

Comment: @VadymPetryshyn is this not cheating? Anyway that question is dumb.

Answer (score 0):

React usually renders into a DOM element you specify, and css defaults will be taken from that dom node.

E.g. in this example, element's css will follow the css of the dom node with id `root`.

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Please look at the screen, I've attached. It mens, correct answer 'inherit'?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is `browser dependent`. It can't be `inherit`. See my [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/vapopopeci/edit?html,css,js,output). I set `display: inline-block` on `#root`. And after rendering `h1` only has browser default value `display: block`.